# Outlook 2016 notification only with new unread email, not old unread emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, notifications, microsoft-outlook-2016, desktop-icons

Currently outlook 2016 always show the yellow mail notification icon. In my mailbox, I have a bunch of read and unread emails. The notification icon seems to always show due to the existing unread emails. How can I set it up so that the notification will only show if new unread email is coming starting from now on?

Answer (score 0):

The yellow envelope icon will show for unread messages that are delivered to the default Inbox for each account configured in your Outlook profile. It's no need to mark all unread emails as read to hide the icon. A restart of Outlook should fix this.